# Xcode 4.4 Mountain Lion, IOS 5.1 simulator. Проблема с Twitter

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone, twitter

Все привет!
Написал простой tweetSheet еще в Xcode на Лайне. После обновления до маунтина, в программе отвалилась поддержка аккаунта в Твиттер. На форуме разработчиков Твиттера пишут что после обновления Xcode на маунтине у всех на симуляторе перестала работать данная функция.

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4850

Вопрос если кто сталкивался: в таком виде поддержка не будет работать и на реальном устройстве, или это проблема только в симуляторе? Не режектят ли в аппсторе сейчас код с добавлением фреймворка твиттер в связи с тем что с IOS 6 будет изменен метод интеграции с соц. сетями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кому-то будет интересно то получена информация о том что данная неполадка - это временный баг симулятора. Предусмотренный Apple код для фреймворка Twitter.framework будет работать на устройстве нормально